# Azure Mobile Service: Serialization of Tables

Tags: c#, android, azure, f#, azure-mobile-services

I have an Azure Mobile App Service, and `PullAsync` is failing silently.

At the back end, the DTO looks like this:

```
type TablesDto() =
    [<JsonProperty("id")>] member val Id = String.Empty with get, set
    [<JsonProperty("deleted")>] member val Deleted = false with get, set
    [<JsonProperty("createdAt")>] member val CreatedAt = Nullable<DateTimeOffset>() with get, set
    [<JsonProperty("updatedAt")>] member val UpdatedAt = Nullable<DateTimeOffset>() with get, set
    [<JsonProperty("version")>] member val Version = [||] with get, set
    interface ITableData with
        member this.Id with get() = this.Id and set(value) = this.Id <- value
        member this.Deleted with get() = this.Deleted and set(value) = this.Deleted <- value
        member this.CreatedAt with get() = this.CreatedAt and set(value) = this.CreatedAt <- value
        member this.UpdatedAt with get() = this.CreatedAt and set(value) = this.UpdatedAt <- value
        member this.Version with get() = this.Version and set(value) = this.Version <- value

type MyEntityDto() =
    inherit TablesDto()
    [<JsonProperty("entityName")>] member val EntityName = String.Empty with get, set
```

I am using a `DomainManager` to map objects from my database schema into this DTO form, but I'm not sure that's relevant.

At the front end (in the Xamarin Android app), the DTO is defined as

```
type MyEntityDto() = 
    [<JsonProperty("id")>] member val Id = String.Empty with get, set
    [<JsonProperty("version"); AzureVersion>] member val Version = Unchecked.defaultof<String> with get, set
    [<JsonProperty("createdAt")>] member val CreatedUtc = DateTime.MinValue with get, set
    [<JsonProperty("updatedAt")>] member val UpdatedUtc = DateTime.MinValue with get, set
    [<JsonProperty("entityName")>] member val EntityName = String.Empty with get, set
```

For debugging purposes, I have used the following handler to inspect the JSON that comes back from the server:

```
#if DEBUG
type DebuggingHandler() =
    inherit DelegatingHandler()
    let deserialise content =
        try 
            let deserialised = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyEntitypDto[]>(content)
            deserialised |> ignore
        with
            | ex -> 
                ex |> ignore
    override this.SendAsync(message, cancellationToken) =
        let sendAsync = base.SendAsync(message, cancellationToken)
        async {
            let! response = sendAsync |> Async.AwaitTask
            let! content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
            deserialise content
            return response
        } |> Async.StartAsTask
#endif
```

Inspecting the `content` value in the debugger shows this:

```
[{"myEntityName@":"Harry","id@":"2","deleted@":true,"createdAt@":"2017-04-26T11:20:46.83Z","updatedAt@":"2017-04-26T11:20:46.83Z","version@":"AAAAAAAAO/Y="},
{"myEntityName@":"Gary","id@":"3","deleted@":false,"createdAt@":"2017-04-26T11:23:05.16Z","updatedAt@":"2017-04-26T11:23:05.16Z","version@":"AAAAAAAAO/c="}]
```

What is happening with this "@" symbol suffix? It prevents the object from deserialising in the debugger, and I suspect this is why the `PullAsync` method is recycling.

Is this some weird side-effect of F#? How can I get rid of these "@" symbols (if that is what is causing my tables sync to break)?

**EDIT** I've added a C# tag because this may be related to the difference between F# and C# in a typical enterprise environment.

Comment: Those are names of internal backing fields of your properties. For some reason, your JSON serializer works with fields instead of properties, even despite them being decorated with attributes.

Comment: Thanks Fyodor. That enabled me to find the answer. TableSync is working correctly now.

Answer (score 2):

Fyodor's comment was the prompt I needed to find the answer.

In Azure mobile apps, the JSON formatters that come out of the box with the table controller can't be trusted to serialise F# objects correctly. So you'll need the following pieces of customisation:

1. Create a formatter that uses JSON.Net:

   ```
   type JsonDotNetFormatter() as this =
       inherit MediaTypeFormatter()
       do this.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"))
       let settings = new JsonSerializerSettings(ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore)
       do settings.ContractResolver <- new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
       override __.CanReadType _ = true
       override __.CanWriteType _ = true
       override __.ReadFromStreamAsync(t, readStream, _, _) =
           async {
               use reader = new StreamReader(readStream)
               let! text = reader.ReadToEndAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
               return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text, t)
           } |> Async.StartAsTask
       override __.WriteToStreamAsync(_, value, writeStream, _, _) =
           async {
               match box value with
               | null -> value |> ignore
               | _ ->
                   let text = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, settings)
                   use writer = new StreamWriter(writeStream)
                   do! writer.WriteAsync(text) |> Async.AwaitTask
           } |> Async.StartAsTask :> Task
   ```
2. Create a config provider, to be used in `Startup.MobileApp.cs`:

   ```
   public class JsonDotNetConfigProvider : TableControllerConfigProvider
   {
       public override void Configure(HttpControllerSettings controllerSettings, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor)
       {
           base.Configure(controllerSettings, controllerDescriptor);
           controllerSettings.Formatters.Insert(0, new JsonDotNetFormatter());
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add the config provider to your mobile app configuration in the `Startup.Configure()` method:

   ```
   new MobileAppConfiguration()
       .AddTablesWithEntityFramework()
       .WithTableControllerConfigProvider(new JsonDotNetConfigProvider())
       .ApplyTo(config);
   ```

This should also work if you run into other generic serialisation issues unrelated to F#. I have mixed C# and F# in this example, but that is something you will probably have to do at some point if you want to write enterprise-level software based on F#.